# Why does the following middleware syntax not work for Express?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm referring to the following example:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js

And specifically the following piece of code:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

The code as posted works just fine. However if I try to refactor it by doing the following:

```
app.post('/login', 
  authenticate,
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

function authenticate() {
    return passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect:'/fail', failureFlash:true });
}
```

things don't work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to invoke `authenticate()` (with the parens), in order to execute the function and return the middleware.  For example:

```
app.post('/login', 
  authenticate(),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

The way you currently have it set up, authenticate is installed as a route handler, so express is calling it with `req`, `res` arguments (which aren't being used or responded to).

Comment: Thanks Jared.  Maybe this is not the right place to ask but how come your original passport.authenticate function does not appear to use req/res either?

Comment: It's a setup function that returns a function taking `req`, `res`, `next` (see http://bit.ly/KGpg3I line 66)

The setup includes the strategy and any options, which the returned function uses.  This setup function returning a function is a common pattern in Express and Connect middleware, and allows some powerful functionality in relatively few lines of code.